# How to convert Datepicker-date to Java.util.Date?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

**ERROR Message**

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '02/23/2013': not a valid representation (error: Can not parse date "02/23/2013": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

**Java object - entity**

```
@Column(name = "event_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date eventDate;
```

**Java Script**

```
$(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });

function formToJSON() {
            return JSON.stringify({
                   "eventDate": $('#datepicker').val()
            });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" placeholder="Date" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
   });
});
```

Comment: +1 this is the simplest solution, if you don't mind the displayed value being formatted that way

Comment: I already tried this one, but I tried that yyyy-MM-dd like error message told me to do, but it wasn't working? This is working fine!. In future what if I want to show localised format like dd/mm/yyyy for instance?

Comment: BTW is there any wiser solution for casting fields to JSON-format? I mean that if you have got 20 fields in a form, I have to write a lot of code just formatting everything? JSON.stringify({
                   "eventDate": $('#datepicker').val()

Answer (score 2):

`datepicker` includes a date formatting utility `$.datepicker.formatDate`

API reference:  [http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/$.datepicker.formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate)

Try this:

```
function formToJSON() {
            var d= $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate')
            return JSON.stringify({
                   "eventDate": $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d)
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better solutions out there, but since this is a problem I often run into and usually can't find a readily available tool, I ended up writing my own functions for that:

```
function dateFormat(date) {
    function two(v) { return v < 10 ? "0" + v : "" + v; }
    function four(v) { return v < 10 ? "000" + v : v < 100 ? "00" + v : v < 1000 ? "0" + v : "" + v; }
    var y = four(date.getFullYear());
    var m = two(date.getMonth()+1);
    var d = two(date.getDate());
    return y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
};

function datetimeFormat(date) {
    function two(v) { return v < 10 ? "0" + v : "" + v; }
    function three(v) { return v < 10 ? "00" + v : v < 100 ? "0" + v : "" + v; }
    function four(v) { return v < 10 ? "000" + v : v < 100 ? "00" + v : v < 1000 ? "0" + v : "" + v; }
    var y = four(date.getUTCFullYear());
    var m = two(date.getUTCMonth()+1);
    var d = two(date.getUTCDate());
    var h = two(date.getUTCHours());
    var mm = two(date.getUTCMinutes());
    var s = two(date.getUTCSeconds());
    var ms = three(date.getUTCMilliseconds());
    return y + "-" + m + "-" + d + "T" + h + ":" + mm + ":" + s + "." + ms;
};
```

The first one is what you need in your particular case, since you're only dealing with dates (and not time).

```
        return JSON.stringify({
               "eventDate": dateFormat($('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate'))
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! Uncaught TypeError: Object 02/28/2013 has no method 'getFullYear'

Comment: @Sami sorry, I forgot that this method needed a `Date` and not a string. Answer updated, but check the other answers too, since they're better.

Comment: yes they are working, but I really appreciate your effort as well!